# Custom icons in sharepoint 2007 document library view

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I need to change the folder icon in a sharpoint document library view.

The catch is, the folder icon is dependent upon various folder properties. So, I need a specific icon for specific folders (I just don't want to change the folder icon across the board).

My initial thoughts were, that if I could find the page (xml or aspx) that sharepoint uses to generate the img tag, I would modify the source to be something like:

src="/GetFolderIcon.aspx?fn={FolderNameHere}"

Where {FolderNameHere} is the actual folder name. Then, in GetFolderIcon.aspx, I would look up the various folder properties, and determine which .gif or .jpeg I needed to send back to the browser.

The problem is, I don't know where that page is located, or what it's even called.

I don't know if that's the correct approach or not, but that's my current thoughts.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a tutoral on something very similar.

http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/09/01/using-calculated-columns-to-write-html/